# Lifetimes added to struct/impl leaves module unresolveable

Tags: struct, rust, lifetime

My project is set up in this fashion:

```
src/lib/rustic_io.rs
src/lib/server.rs
src/main.rs
```

**main.rs**

```
#[path="lib/rustic_io.rs"]
mod rustic_io;

fn main() {

    // Setup information (Server is not started yet)
    let mut server = rustic_io::listen("127.0.0.1", 1338);

    // Event with data to listen for
    server.on("connection", |data: &str| {
        // Do stuff in here with data
    });

    // Start server
    server.start();
}
```

**rustic_io.rs**

```
mod server;

/*
 * Returns a new Server to start WebSocket Protocol
 */
pub fn listen(ip_addr: &str, port_num: u16) -> server::Server {
    server::Server::new(String::from_str(ip_addr), port_num)
}
```

**server.rs**

```
pub struct Server<'srv> {
    ip: String,
    port: u16,
    events: Vec<Event<'srv>>
}

impl &'a Server {

    // Constructs a Server object
    pub fn new<'a>(ip_addr: String, port_num: u16) -> Server<'a> {
        Server {
            ip: ip_addr,
            port: port_num,
            events: Vec::new()
        }
    }

    pub fn on(&self, event: &str, execute: |data: &str|) {
        // Do some stuff
    }

    pub fn start(&self) {
        // Start up all the things
    }
}

mod event {
    pub struct Event<'a> {
        name: String,
        execute: |data: &str|:'a
    }
}
```

Everything was working fine until I wanted to start adding a vector of `Event` type to the `Server` struct.  In order to add a closure as a property, it needed a lifetime.  Got that in there with a little help from SO.  Then, in order to have a `Vec<Event>` in the `Server` struct, it needed a lifetime as well.  Once the server struct was all lifetime'd out, the `impl` now needed lifetimes.  After getting the lifetime going in the implementation part, when I try and compile I now get

```
error: failed to resolve. Not a module `Server`
```

Pointing to this statement: `server::Server::new(String::from_str(ip_addr), port_num)`

I feel that I have a decent grasp on lifetimes when it comes to using them on various variables inside a function, but am clueless as to what is what with lifetimes when designing your own structure and implementations.  Why does the server module stop becoming resolvable when the implementation uses a lifetime?  I feel like I am going about this in the complete opposite way I should be and have the lifetime specifiers out of whack...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This isn't a lifetime problem. I was able to get your code to compile with the following:

1. `impl &'a Server { ... }` is not valid syntax. Change it to `impl<'a> Server<'a> { ... }`
2. Change `Vec<Event<'srv>>` to `Vec<event::Event<'srv>>`.

You can also change the `fn new<'a>` to `fn new` in the impl block.